# Error code 2 when compiling a cpp file in notepad++

Tags: command-line, notepad++, nppexec

I'm using this code

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ $(FILE_NAME) -o $(FILE_NAME).exe
```

to run a cpp from notepad. What I had expected to run was `g++ FILE_NAME.cpp -o FILE_NAME.exe`
But `g++ FILE_NAME.cpp -o FILE_NAME.cpp.exe` is what I got.

So how do I include only the file name (without the extension) so that this code works?
Is there some code to access the file name (without the extension)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable `$(NAME_PART)` should just return the filename without file extension.

So your code would look like this;

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ $(NAME_PART) -o $(NAME_PART).exe
```